# material not fading alpha smoothly in blender internal

Tags: animation, materials, transparency

I have animated the alpha value of a material. At one frame, the material is all dark, at the next´, it is as it should be.

Here is the material in the two frames:
[image: material in two frames]

I was hoping that you could give me an idea what went wrong.